# Is the new control map on .NET upgraded?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, dictionary, bing-maps

Did anyone notice that the new map control in wp8 (the one in the tools box) is not upgraded? I mean, I've ran my application and saw that places I know exactly like the palm of my hand don't look like the maps on google maps or bing maps. It seems that the new control map is not upgraded. Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess you're talking about the map being shown (fetched online via the web) rather than the actual control? Could be old cached map tiles you have on the phone?

Comment: sorry.. i don't have a windows phone, i am just building an app using map control on windows phone emulator 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes!

Long answer, in fact, updates are distributed in two ways in the WP8 control depending on the way you are using the Maps application.

- If you chose to download offline maps (like if you want to be able to used without using your data connection), then the Map control will use the offline data and you can get regular updates by checking in the same place you chose the area to download
- If you are not using the offline maps, then you're using the data that are available directly online coming from the server and then it's already the latest information and it might be cached for a small time

If you want to check if the data are available on Bing, check on the bing official portal: http://bing.com/maps/ ; if you don't have the same data, it might be due to one of the previous reasons.

Comment: ok.. i forgot to say i am building an app using maps.. it is posible to "update" the map control en wp8 so in the future i will be able to see map places upgraded, included in new apps?

Comment: New places will be added with the other data information whatever the version of the map control you're using. So in short, if you use the map control, content will be added as soon as they're added in the Bing or Here data on their server or in their offline packages.